# Chapter spacing differs on odd and even pages (twoside report)

Tags: spacing, double-sided

My horizontal chapter spacings are different on odd and even pages and I don't want this, the titles should be in the same place on all the pages.
I believe this is because I use a twosided report as document class, but I want to keep it twosided. How can I fix the chapter spacing?
I also use a different titleformat, but even without this the problem occurs.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

%optional changing the titleformat
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp{$|$}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1}
\chapter{chapter 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use single-sided? The two-sided changes the margins of odd and even. That's what two-sided is for

Comment: I use twosided because i have a lot of pages that should start on the right side and then I can use  \cleardoublepage. or is there another solution for this?

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102462/90297

Comment: Yes it does thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate so that we won't get irrelevant answers